# How to adjust result of randoming

Tags: matlab

I have a problem adjusting the result of number randoming,

```
jum_k = 14;
jum_b = 12;

result = randint(jum_k, jum_b, [0 2]);
```

so that there is a constraint on the final result. There should not be a value "0" appearing more than three times in row.

Answer (score 1):

Your random entries are then non-uniformly distributed with unknown weights, i.e. the number of zero per line can be <=3 ([0, 1, 2, 3]). I would hack around it this way: Populate an `[m x n]` matrix uniformly in [1,2], choose (random) number of zeros per line, then choose (random) their locations. Example:

```
jum_k = 14;
jum_b = 12;

result = randi([1, 2], jum_k, jum_b);
for i = 1:jum_k
    nZeros = randi([0, 3]); % number of zeros (random)
    result(i, randi(jum_b, 1, nZeros)) = 0; % locations in line (random)
end;
```

If you need an exact number of zeros per line you can modify accordingly.

**EDIT** (after clarifications on question from comments): To accomodate for no more than 3 zeros in sequence per each line, e.g. `[1,0,0,0...2]` you can populate the matrix element-wise and check for the pattern [0,0,0,0] in previous elements (keeping a buffer of previous values).

```
result = nan(jum_k, jum_b); % intitialize
for i = 1:jum_k
    for j = 1:jum_b
        result(i, j) = randi([0, 2]); % assign value       
        if j>3 && ~all(result(i, j-3:j)) % check previous values
            result(i, j-randi([0, 3])) = randi([1, 2]); % randomly change one 
        end
    end
end

%% check/test that all lines have less 4 zeros in sequence
f = @strfind;
for i = 1:jum_k
    t(i) = isempty(f(result(i,:),[0 0 0 0]));
end
T = all(t);
```

It's not optimal (MATLAB-wise) but will do the job.

Comment: but i think your code will make number of zero in each row will be <=3. but i mean not like that. actually how many zero in each row is not problem, but the problem is the matrix result cannot contain (appear) value "zeros" more than three times in row in each row. so what can i modify from your code??

Comment: the above code will give you a matrix of values [0,1,2] where the zeros in each line are at most 3. If I understood correctly this is what you wanted, or not?

Comment: not Mr. Gevang. actually, no matter how much number of zeros in each line/row. but the problem is how make those value zeros will not appears more than three times in a row. example : it cannot be " 1 0 0 0 0 2 ". we have to avoid it happend

Comment: now it's clear. you should have re-phrased the original question and providing the example though. The terms `row` (refering to line) and `row` refering to sequence can be confusing when used on the same sentence. See the edited answer for a possible solution to this.

Comment: thanks Mr. gevang, but that code will make each row only have less than 4 zeros. but i want no constraint about how many number zeros. just let it random. i just want to give constraint about sequence of zeros that result cannot contain value "0" more than three time in a row.

Comment: it does not constrain the total number of zeros per line. It is random. You can have more than 4. Did you try increasing `jum_k` and `jum_b` to test it?

Comment: yeah you are right. but why when i give another constraint. it did not work yah mr. my another constraint is that sum all element each row has to be <=11. hehe sorry make you little bit busy.

Comment: so actually my case is how to make a matrix with dimension (14,12,10) which has value random [0 2], each row cannot contain value "0" more than three times in a row (sequence, not how many number of zeros), and then sum of all value in each row must be <=11.